# Which term is better for the so called "sphere packing"?

Tags: sphere-packing, circle-packing, terminology

I'm working on sphere packings. When I write, I'm confused with basic definitions. I'm hesitating between the terms "sphere", "ball" or "oriented sphere".

For example, on the wikipedia page of [circle packing theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem)

> A circle packing is a connected collection of circles whose interiors are disjoint.

But rigorously, a circle (1-sphere) is the boundary of a disk (2-ball). A sphere has no interior, a ball has. The interior is important for the definition of packings.

The problem becomes serious if I want to include hyperplanes as generalised spheres, or if I want to use the usual exterior as the interior (negatively curved balls)

I also read in literature definitions like

> A sphere packing is a collection of balls with disjoint interiors

I prefer this one, but why not call it a "ball packing" directly as [here](http://intlpress.com/_newsite/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/1996/0003/0001/MRL-1996-0003-0001-A-005.pdf)?
I tend to use "ball packing", but since almost every others is using "sphere packing", I'm wondering if I missed something important by calling these objects "balls". (For example, google with "Apollonian ball packing" returns no result.)

Another solution is "oriented sphere", as in [Lie sphere geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_sphere_geometry). Then my question is, what's the difference (in practice) between a sphere with an orientation, and a ball with an interior?

Comment: Best terminology: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelpackung  :-)

Comment: I don't think it's the world's most interesting question, but I also don't see why there are votes to close.  It seems harmless enough.   

Comment: Certainly "ball packing" is a more logical name than "sphere packing" according to modern mathematical conventions, but "sphere packing" is traditional.  It doesn't cause any serious confusion, and I prefer the sound of it (maybe just because I'm used to it).  It's possible that the community will gradually drift towards "ball packing" over time, but I don't see movement in that direction; if it does happen, it is likely to be pretty slow, especially since there are advantages to using the same terminology as most other people.

Comment: I don't know if the OP is a native English speaker. To me, "ball packing" evokes associations that are distracting ... sort of like the junior high school giggles you get when you talk about Uranus.

Comment: @Ben: if you think that is bad, I heard a talk by a mathematical physicist where he remarked that online  searches for information on the hard-core model (of gases, in statistical mechanics) gave, erm, results of a different nature